# Hiding a client side checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net, input, checkbox, visible

I have a checkbox which looks like:

```
<input id="chkSelectAll" name="chkSelectAll" type="checkbox"/>
```

Now in a button I want to be able to hide that control so far I have:

```
chkSelectAll.Visible = false;
```

But I can't access the properties of that control since it's client side.

I can't use Server Side checkbox also so don't suggest that.

Any help to how I can make the checkbox property of visible to 'false' will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any reasons not to use runat attribute? If you can't use server side checkbox how are you going to disable it in server side? Other way would be to use Javascript...

Comment: you can use javascript or jQuery

Comment: can't u use jquery or javascript?

Comment: `chkSelectAll.Visibility=hidden;`

Comment: It needs to be done in the Server Side

Comment: @user2836518 if you want to do it in server side then put a runat="server" in there...

Comment: But then that won't make the Checkbox client side, I need the checkbox to remain client side but change it's properties in the server side

Comment: in your jquery use ClientID to get unique id of checkbox as Adil's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can change DOM properties on server side using control.Attributes or control.Styles

Using DOM element property on **Server Side** code behind.

```
chkSelectAll.Styles.Add('display', 'none');
```

Or

```
chkSelectAll.Attributes.Add('style', 'display:none');
```

You can do that using `ClientID` in javascript / jQuery on **Client Side**

*Using javascript*

```
document.getElementById('<%= chkSelectAll.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

*Using jQuery*

```
$('#<%= chkSelectAll.ClientID %>').hide();
```

Comment: I don't have them options when I start to type it in

Comment: I still don't have 'attributes' since the checkbox is client side

Comment: Why dont you make it server accessibly but putting runat="server" ?

Comment: +1 use runat="server" and in jquery use $('#<%= chkSelectAll.ClientID %>').hide(); this will get you the unique id of control if it has been changed by masterpage

Comment: Because my checkbox is doing other stuff which doesn't allow me to make it server side; the code I gave was a skeleton, there is a lot more code, if I wanted it to work server side I would of. This question doesn't answer what I asked

Comment: @user2836518 it does answer it. The only thing runtat="server" would do is change your id, and as I said you can get the control's ID by JQuery ClietnID...

Comment: Nope; just did it and doesn't work, therefore the post isn't the solution to my problem

Comment: @user2836518 another solution would be to put runat=server and have the ClientIDMode of control to static...see if that works

Comment: The thing is; my checkbox has an OnClick event which calls some JavaScript code:
<input id="chkSelectAll" name="chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAllCheckboxes();"  /> Select All

Once I add in 'runat = "server"' this disabled the use of being able to do the client side onclick, this is why it needs to stay client side

Comment: @user2836518 if you put runat="server" your javascript function onclick would fire. If you don't believe me create a small project and test :D

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is not a server control but just a client control, then what you can do is to change the styles of this checkbox:
display: none
you can do it with jQuery , for example. Something like this: $("#chb").css("display", "none");
You should put this functionality into some function and call it from your client side when, for example, you click on a button